# Excel - find last value in a column which is not an error or blank

Tags: arrays, excel, function, spreadsheet

I need to find in a column of an excel spreadsheet the last non-error, non-blank value. The column can have several instaces of #N/A which are alternating with actual values. There are several solutions for finding the last non-empty cell, but the solutions do not consider errors, in particular if the last non-empty cell has got an error.

The solution would be 3 in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this formula

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A100<>""),A1:A100)`

extend range as required. In Excel 2007 and later you can use the whole column

Comment: Gave the exact answer. Maybe I can ask you in addition, if I would want to know the index/row of this value, how would I rewrite it? I still need to figure out how your equation works, before attempting to answer the index question.

Comment: If you want the ROW you can simply add ROW function to the 2nd part, i.e. =LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A100<>""),ROW(A1:A100)) or use MATCH =MATCH(2,1/(A1:A100<>"")) which is an "array formula" to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.....or non-array version =MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(A1:A100<>""),0)) . Note that MATCH gives the row number `within the range` so if range starts at a row other than 1 it won't match the ROW version which gives the absolute row number - I'll add an explanation also to the above....

Comment: Brilliant. Worked exactly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate #N/A error cells by using IFERROR(. . .

then

{=MAX(COLUMN(A4:A150)*(A4:A150<>0))} if A1 -style

or

{=MAX(COLUMN(RC4:RC150)*(RC4:RC150<>0))} if RC -style

{} ... array formula . .. ctrl+shift+enter

For Row - replace COLUMN with ROW