# Excel - find value in row which is not an error or blank

Tags: arrays, excel, lookup

Someone posted a question about doing this for a column but I don't understand the answer well enough to tweak it to work for data in a row. Can someone help me understand how this formula works and how to apply it to data in rows? I want to display the non error value in a new column, not the number of the row or column.

Thanks!

Try this formula

=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A100<>""),A1:A100)

extend range as required. In Excel 2007 and later you can use the whole column

Original question here: [Excel - find last value in a column which is not an error or blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100119/excel-find-last-value-in-a-column-which-is-not-an-error-or-blank)

Comment: Usually VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP is better, but in this particular case they're taking advantage of a difference in the older LOOKUP's reaction to not finding the search value.  LOOKUP will return the last non-matching value, while HLOOKUP will return #N/A.

Answer (score 2):

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/(A1:G1<>""),A1:G1)
```

Just change the range in both places.

Comment: Hah, I can't believe I didn't just try that. Thanks so much!